# Getting errors on creating new project using command 'ng new <project_name>' after upgrading to version 9

Tags: angular9

Please find the stack over here...

Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...iERRHPyU8nBqZB1+iv2Uh'

Comment: Having same issue! Anyone please help on this

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error and was able to fix it through following steps.

Run npm cache clean --force
Manually delete npm and npm-cache folders from AppData/Roaming folder (Win + R, Type %AppData% and enter)
Run Node Installer and repair
Reinstall npm install -g @angular/cli
Rerun ng new newApp
Worked :)
**Use node V12.4.0 and npm V6.9.0**

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same issue please try reinstall angular CLI after installing previous one

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only be achieved if we first update the version to 8 and then move from 8 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue and Following steps worked for me.

1. Delete npm-cache in AppData/Roaming
2. Reinstall the angular cli by 'npm install -g @angular/cli'

Then Create the project

Answer (score 0):

1. Run npm cache clean --force
2. Manually delete npm and npm-cache folders from AppData/Roaming folder (Win + R, Type %AppData% and enter)
3. Run Node Installer and repair
   4.Reinstall npm install -g @angular/cli

Rerun ng new newApp
Worked :)

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1191

Answer (score 0):

Delete the AppData\Roaming\npm-cache folder and then try creating the project again. This is really gonna work =)